# Unable to do homog.test in a loop

Tags: r

I have a problem looping through columns with this command. When printing "i", the variable name appears, but it does not substitute it in the formula. The error suggested that I can't use a variable. Any suggestions?

```
for (i in colnames(NMDStrokeHx)[3:14]){
  print(i)
  print(homog.test(i ~ AM25, data = NMDStrokeHx, method = "Levene"))
}
```

output:
[1] "ANCOWATO"
Error in homog.test(i ~ AM25, data = NMDStrokeHx, method = "Levene") :
The name of response variable does not match the variable names in the data.

```
these are the column names of the data:
> colnames(NMDStrokeHx)[3:14]
 [1] "ANCOWATO" "ANMSETOT" "ANAFTOT"  "ANBNTTOT" "ANDELCOR" "ANWM2TOT" "ANFULVR1" "ANVRTCOR" "ANTMASEC"
[10] "ANTMBSEC" "ANSDMTOT" "ADCDRSTG"
```

Comment: Please provide a working example that reproduces the error. We need to see your data to understand what is going on. For example, we need to know the names of the variables in your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reformulate`/`as.formula` to create a formula object.

```
for (i in colnames(NMDStrokeHx)[3:14]){
  print(i)
  print(homog.test(reformulate('AM25', i), data = NMDStrokeHx,method = "Levene"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I still get error messages:
> for (i in colnames(NMDStrokeHx)[3:14]){
+   print(i)
+   print(homog.test(reformulate(i,"AM25" ), data = NMDStrokeHx,method = "Levene"))
+ }
[1] "ANCOWATO"
Error in homog.test(reformulate(i, "AM25"), data = NMDStrokeHx, method = "Levene") : 
  The group variable must be a factor. 

>   print(homog.test(as.formula(i ~ "AM25"), data = NMDStrokeHx,method = "Levene"))
Error in homog.test(as.formula(i ~ "AM25"), data = NMDStrokeHx, method = "Levene") : 
  The name of response variable does not match the variable names in the data.

Comment: You don't have `AM25` column name in your data?

Comment: i included the column names in the question statement. it works when i replace i with "ANCOWATO"

Comment: @VennisiaMo Yes, so include only the columns that is present in your data.

Comment: but i *is* equal to something in the columns

Comment: Ok..I cannot debug/comment further without some data to test this. Please update your question with output of `dput(NMDStrokeHx)` or `dput(head(NMDStrokeHx, 10))`